Show that $Y$ is homeomorphic to the connected sum $\mathbb {RP}^3 \# \mathbb {RP}^3$ using surgery, identifications, then reattachment.
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. The only recommended book for this question is Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. My notation is in line with what I see commonly used in the textbooks that I study out of, but if there are requests for clarifying notation then I will happily oblige. I have seen no proof for this problem in any textbook; all work is my own, so I want to make sure my own unique solution looks good.

Consider the space $Y$ obtained from $S^2 \times \left[ 0,1\right]$ by identifying $(x, 0)$ with $(-x, 0)$ and also identifying $(x,1)$ with $(-x,1)$, for all $x \in S^2$. Show that $Y$ is homeomorphic to the connected sum $\mathbb {RP}^3 \# \mathbb {RP}^3 $.
Answer: I went for a concise geometric argument rather than a heavily algebraic one, similar to some of the proofs I've seen done by Milnor and Arnol'd.
Perform surgery: Cut $S^2 \times [0,1]$ into two pieces and obtain the disjoint union $\left(S^2 \times [0, 1/2] \right) + \left(S^2 \times [1/2 , 1]\right)$. Take the quotients of both components and obtain $$ { S^2 \times [0, 1/2] \over S^2 \times \{ 1/2 \}} + { S^2 \times [1/2 , 1] \over S^2 \times \{ 1/2\}}  \approx C(S^2) + C(S^2)$$ which is the disjoint union of two cones. Each cone is homeomorphic to the upper hemisphere of $S^3$. Have $x \sim (-x)$ if $x$ is an equatorial point (which, if you recall, were the points corresponding previously to $S^2 \times \{0\}$ and $S^2 \times \{1\}$). Then we have $$ {C(S^2 ) \over \sim} +  {C(S^2 ) \over \sim} \approx \mathbb{RP}^3 + \mathbb{RP}^3$$
For each copy of $\mathbb {RP}^3$, cut out a ball $B^3$ on the upper hemisphere. Then we have a hole with boundary $\partial B^3 = S^2$. Use these holes to perform the connected sum; attach both punctured copies of $\mathbb {RP}^3$ to each other by aligning and gluing each hole properly. This region of attachment between both hemispheres is homeomorphic to $S^2 \times (0, 1)$, which completes our proof.

Does this sequential application of surgery, taking the cone, identifying, and taking the connected sum demonstrate the homeomorphism well?

what's (X, ) there above?

@janmarqz Thanks for noticing! I made the fix.

It's not necessary to frame this argument in terms of surgery, but if you do, you have to provide the punchline for this to be a demonstration: The connected sum of two (connected, oriented) $n$-manifolds $M,N$ is obtained from their disjoint union $M\sqcup N$ by performing surgery along $S^0\rightarrow M\sqcup N$ (with a coherently oriented framing), where one point maps into each factor. Thus, to identify a third (oriented) $n$-manifold $P$ as homeomorphic to $M\# N$, it suffices to find an $(n-1)$-sphere $S^{n-1}\rightarrow P$ (with a coherently oriented framing) s.t. performing surgery along it results in $M\sqcup N$ with dual sphere $S^0\rightarrow M\sqcup N$ as before. The latter is what you appear to do (at the same time, the final paragraph of your demonstration is unnecessary if you take this approach, so I'm not quite sure what you're going for there).
Let me also point out that you have not addressed any orientation concerns (though, $\mathbb{R}P^3$ admits an orientation-reversing homeomorphism, so the connected sum is well-defined without orientation concerns in this case, but that should at least be stated). Also, technically, you glue a $D^3$ along each boundary $S^2$ when performing surgery rather than collapsing them, but this yields the same result due to the (in this case, explicit) existence of collars.
The actual geometric content of your demonstration is perfectly sound.
